# PHP - Filter_var alternative?

Tags: php, sanitize, filter-var

I built a php script to output data posted in a form, but I ran into a problem. The server the website is going to run on, runs PHP 5.1.6. This version of PHP does not support filter_var.

I need to know an alternative on short term (preferably yesterday), and can't find something straight forward on Google or Stack Overflow.

Mayhap someone here ran into the same issue in the past and has a quick fix for me?

This code:

```
$email= filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
$answer= filter_var($_POST['answer'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

needs to be compatible with PHP 5.1.6, so the email address is checked on genuinity, and that no malicious code is used in either fields. Any tips?

Thanks so much!

Comment: use regular expressions instead of filter_var is the only option.

Comment: regex is a little bit heavy-weight for simple text-replacing. Consider functions defined for that purpose: mysql_real_escape_string(), htmlentities(), addslashes(), ....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for Emails you can use a Regex:  (for example: http://www.totallyphp.co.uk/validate-an-email-address-using-regular-expressions)

for strings you could also do regex, but that is a little bit too heavy, so maybe a combination of `mysql_real_escape_string()` if you send it to a DB, and for html you should use `htmlentities()`:

http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

I don't think that the filter_var-function does far different than just using these methods

Comment: Thanks, EGOrecords. I'll use your example given for the E-mails, and htmlentities for the strings. If anyone else has the same problem in the future, here's a great start to help you with the htmlentities: http://codeassembly.com/How-to-sanitize-your-php-input/

Comment: ...this really should've been given the tick =)

Answer (score 2):

You can install the extension via PECL to PHP 5.1:
http://pecl.php.net/package/filter

Comment: If he cannot update to a more recent PHP-Version he cannot install a PHP-Extension (because you always need deeper access to the server...)

Comment: Frankly though, EGOrecords is right. Nevertheless, thanks for the input. :)

Answer (score 2):

i would use a regular expression generally. it provides you the most flexibility. on the internet are many useful resources about it. take a look [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) or [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regex)

Answer (score -1):

Using the information I was given in the previous answers, here's how I fixed my problem:

```
<?PHP // Retreive POST data and sanitize it: trim string, no HTML, plain text
$variable1=htmlentities(trim($_POST['input1']), ENT_NOQUOTES);
$variable2=htmlentities(trim($_POST['input2']), ENT_NOQUOTES);
$emailaddress=$_POST['email']; // sanitizing email address happens below

if(eregi("^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$", $emailadres)){    // check email address and if legit, do this:
        echo '<p>The e-mail address given is valid.</p>'

} else{ // if email is not legit, do this:
        echo '<p>The e-mail address given is not valid.</p>';
}
?>
```

I hope this helps someone :)